# Display table in a Tcl Tk window with R

Tags: r, dataframe, tktable

I want to display data frame table in a new window using Tcl Tk tool. 
´tktable´ must be the solution but I don't know how to use it with data frame.
Can anyone show me how?

Comment: OS? Would you consider using gwidgets which sits on top of TclTk in Windows?

Comment: Windows XP, but it will also run on seven. And I am already using gwidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
library( gWidgets )
x <- data.frame( a = runif( 20 ), b = runif( 20 ) * 100, c = rnorm( 20 ), 
                 d = sample( LETTERS, 20 ), e = 1000:1019, f = rep( "Table Test", 20 ) )

win <- gwindow( "Table", visible = FALSE )
table <- gtable( x, cont = win )
visible( win ) <- TRUE
```